# Handling AJAX concurrency problems in the database

Tags: ajax, postgresql, concurrency

We are building an ajax application. We would like it to be possible for several users to access the application at the same time. Therefore, I have the idea of running every update query in a way so that they supply the previous value of the fields. The point is that PostgreSQL should throw an error if the previous value was not what the system expected it to be (meaning that someone else modified it after our user was presented with the value). It would be neat to handle this in one transaction and on database level since that there are no concurrency problems. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Therefore, I have the idea of running every update query in a way so that they supply the previous value of the fields

You are describing a trick known as "optimistic concurrency control" or "optimistic locking". It's well-established and proven.

See:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimistic_concurrency_control
- http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/transactions.html#transactions-optimistic (for Hibernate, a Java ORM, but the principles apply to many systems)

Even ODBC back in the year dot did this, though the original approach used by ODBC has some ... issues.

It's generally much better to have a dedicated revision column, which should be an integer that's incremented with every update. Don't use a timestamp.

You can do something like:

```
SELECT col1, version FROM sometable WHERE id = 42;
```

Imagining you get the result row `('bob',7)` you'd then run:

```
UPDATE sometable SET col1 = 'fred' WHERE id = 42 AND version = 7;
```

and check how many rows are affected. If it's zero, you know there was an update collision.

If you mix optimistic-locking and conventional applications in the same database you can use [a trigger to make sure the optimistic locking column always gets incremented](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Hibernate_oplocks) so that your conventional apps and op-locking apps play well together.

This strategy *does not work* on trigger-partitioned tables in PostgreSQL, by the way.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this in the database, I think you will have to use a trigger on the table.  In the trigger, you have the ability to check the "old" (what's in the table now) against the "new" (what you're sending in for the update).  I don't think that you can use rules for this.  You could also use a last modified column in the table instead of passing and comparing all the columns.

```
CREATE TRIGGER check_update
  BEFORE UPDATE ON table
  FOR EACH ROW
  WHEN (OLD.timestamp IS DISTINCT FROM NEW.timestamp)
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE check_update();
```

If you don't want to use the timestamp, you can have all the column checks in the WHEN clause.  You could then have the check_update() procedure do something, maybe raise an exception or return the data as it exists now.  There are probably better ways, but this should work.

Answer (score 0):

The postgreSQL [MVCC](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/mvcc.html) model could ensure that no one is altering data while your user transaction reads and save data alterations. This would especially be enforced by using the [serializable transaction level](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/transaction-iso.html#XACT-SERIALIZABLE)... **BUT**.

Your real problem is not the save phase, where it would be easy to open a transaction, read data, alter it and commit this transaction; your problem is the web thing. **You cannot open a transaction, read data, push it to the end user via your web application and then wait for some seconds/minutes days for the ajax request, then save altered data and commit**. Transactions are not made to stay open for very long time and be resumed after user post.

So on the web application server side what you have is a form post and you want to save altered data. You especially want to detect data that would have been altered between the time your user loaded the page, went to eat something, and decided to press the submit button. One way to do that is to store a copy of the original unaltered data in your user post, and compare this data with the current storage data. Another way is to stamp the data records in the database with something like @Scott S's solution, a last modification timestamp. and recompute it after each modification (maybe using triggers). Then you would embed this (or theses) data signature(s) on the user forms and after opening the saving transaction the first thing you would do would be to compare the md5sum and rollback the whole operation if data seem to have been altered.

This is not the database role, it's an **application logic**, as the database will only manage asynchronous data manipulation (the transactions isolation management and locks) and not long term user shared data policies. Your application must handle the sharing policies via asynchronous forms lobd and posts. See for example the way wikipedia handle it. If you load the same page in edit mode from several places and try to save both, previous modifications are deteceted and your second save is rejected. To be honnest the vast majority of web applications igores this problen and the last submit won.

**UPDATE**

To go further with ajax management of synchronous modification you could build a quite complex system, using [LISTEN](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-listen.html) and [NOTIFY](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-notify.html) SQL keywords to detect modifications and **push back theses things on client side**. If your application server is persistent (not like PHP or jsp) and if you use persistent ajax connection emulations with systems like [comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29) or other [push technology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology), then you could notify users on the web form when another user has made a transaction commit altering some of the data shown in his form. This would not remove the problem of users submitting modification at a very near time (parallel user request handling server side). For this last case your only solution is to use a nice transaction, maybe in serializable lever, and **always manage the fact that a user modification may be rejected server side** (this is the key of transacions, always manage the fact a transaction can be rolled back by the server even if you made no mistakes, simply because the modifications are conflicting with a parallel commited transaction).

Comment: Using `LISTEN` and `NOTIFY` to alert the user to conflicts is useful. The rest is way over-complicated though; just use a revision counter column, it's simple, reliable, and easily enforced.

Comment: @Craig Ringer: even a revision counter can be badly managed if you just increment it in two parallel transactions if you are not in serialized level, so in most transactional modes you should read/check the version IN your transaction and ensure the right row lock and/or transaction abort.